# Not authenticated error in Deluge Web JSON API

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-requests

I'm using Python requests library to send a JSON request to a Deluge Web torrentbox running on my Raspberry Pi.

```
import requests
payload='{"method": "auth.login", "params": ["MY-PASSWORD"], "id": 1}'
r = requests.post("http://192.168.0.104:8112/json", data=payload)
print r.headers
print r.text
payload2='{"method": "core.add_torrent_magnet", "params": ["MAGNET-URI", {}], "id": 2}'
q = requests.post("http://192.168.0.104:8112/json", data=payload2)
print q.headers
print q.text
print "---------------"
```

On running the above code, I get the successful authentication, but my 2nd request gives an error, "Not authenticated"

OUTPUT

> {'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
>   'Set-Cookie': '_session_id=d888b2548fd6966490eef4b3657a1b342169;
>   Expires=Sun, 08 May 2016 14:22:45 GMT; Path=/json', 'Server':
>   'TwistedWeb/12.0.0', 'Date': 'Sun, 08 May 2016 13:22:45 GMT','Content-Type': 'application/x-json'} {"id": 1, "result": true,"error": null}
>
> ---

---

> {'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Sun, 08 May 2016 13:22:45 GMT', 'Server': 'TwistedWeb/12.0.0', 'Content-Type':
>   'application/x-json', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip'} {"id": 2, "result":
>   null, "error": **{"message": "Not authenticated", "code": 1}}**

If I run the 2nd request using curl, it works.

```
curl -b cookies.txt --compressed -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{"method": "core.add_torrent_magnet", "params": ["MAGNET_URI", {}], "id": 1}' http://localhost:8112/json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
The session cookies were not getting shared because I ran each request using different objects. Started a session using :

```
r=requests.session()
```

Then ran each request by calling the POST requests on r only.